# Facebook iOS SDK "Access your basic profile info AND list of Friends" remove Friends

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Using the Facebook SDK for iOS and have the following basic login code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;

[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self
 handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

     NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     [parameters setValue:@"id,name" forKey:@"fields"];

     [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
      startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                   id result, NSError *error) {


          NSLog(@"%@", result);
      }];
 }];
```

I ONLY want the basic profile information hence the call to `public_profile`

However, when I make the call, I get the following: "MyApp" would like to access your basic profile info and **list of friends**."

I don't want to access list of friends. When I go to the "MyApp" on facebook I can see it correctly only has access to the basic profile information.

How can I modify the prompt so my user doesn't think I need any of their friend info?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new App, the friend list was included in older App versions without the need to add `user_friends` to your scope. Should not even be possible anymore because that was before v2.0, but you never know. Could be a bug. If it does not work in a new App and you are really not using the `user_friends` scope, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a brand new app just created a few days ago.

Comment: in that case, it does sound like a bug, if you really don´t use user_friends anywhere.

Comment: after authorizing in your app, you could try calling /me/friends in the api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ - the result would be interesting.